# Switching MySql Replication Format

Tags: mysql, replication

I'm currently using statement-based replication.  After upgrading to MySql 5.1, I'm considering using row-based replication.

After reading the docs it seems that you can change the format of the master on the fly.

Will the slave automatically adapt to whatever type of binary log it is sent?

Do I have to make any changes to the slave or master to get ready for switching or can I simply modify the binlog_format variable on the master?

Answer (score 2):

The binary log format only needs to be changed on the master using the binlog_format variable. The master does not need to start new binary logs as the log file can contain both events in STATEMENT and ROW format. The slave will automatically switch when encountering the events in either format in the fetched binary log.